# Floating div overlapping

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

I am working on a html web designe. I have three divs.. one is header, then middle,  footer. all are 1200px width  header has the height of 150px. footer has the heights of 150px. I made the height of the middle is auto, min-height:500px. then I placed two other divs inside the middle div.both divs are float: left. height:auto. now the problem is that when the contant of this divs is more than min height of 500 0px the contant overlaps the footer... the size of the middle is not increasing

Comment: post some code so that people can help you... a fiddle?

Comment: Please add you code.

Comment: Sounds like you need to `clear` the `div`s in the middle container.

Comment: try to use display:block and clear:both for div's. If u show the code, it will be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:-

```
.clr{clear: both;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/pcwpoech/)**

OR

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/pcwpoech/1/)**

You  can use clearfix class also

```
.clearfix:after{content:'';display:block;clear:both}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

//CSS

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Then add  after float of divs

//HTML

```
   <div class="middle-content">
     <div class="sample"></div>
     <div class="sample"></div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
```